# Como posso fazer funcionar a função filter (dplyr) em um loop?

Tags: r, loop, dplyr

Então, vou estar utilizando o çars para ilustrar melhor. Estou com um código para inicialmente selecionar um intervalo na primeira coluna do dataframe e dentro deste intervalo devo retornar o menor valor da segunda coluna. Segue exemplo com o cars, em que eu seleciono o intervalo [4:10] e retorno a linha com o menor valor de dist:

```
 a <- cars %>% filter(between(speed, 4, 10)) 

 a %>% slice_min(dist)

 speed dist

 1     4    2
```

Porém estou com problemas para aplicar isso no loop for, pois eu preciso fazer isto cobrindo todo o intervalo do dataframe. Da forma que eu fiz ficou assim

```
for (i in 4:25) {

  a <- cars %>% filter(between(speed, i, i + 3))
 
  b <- a %>% slice_min(dist)

  print(b)
  
  i == i + 3
  
}
```

Porém ele está retornando valores muito estranhos que não correspondem aos menores valores do intervalo. Algum palpite?

Answer (score 4):

## 1. Ciclo `for`

Com um ciclo `for` é melhor criar primeiro uma lista onde guardar os resultados de cada iteração.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
  
speed_vec <- 4:(25 - 3)
results <- vector("list", length = length(speed_vec))

for(i in seq_along(speed_vec)) {
  s <- speed_vec[i]
  results[[i]] <- cars %>% 
    filter(between(speed, s, s + 3)) %>%
    slice_min(dist)
}
results <- do.call(rbind, results)
head(results)
#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
#> 2     7    4
#> 3     7    4
#> 4     7    4
#> 5     9   10
#> 6     9   10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## 2. Com `purrr::map`

O pacote `purrr` tem as funções `map_*` que permitem ter a saída da aplicação de uma função no formato desejado, neste caso `map_dfr` para ter um data.frame e `r` de `rows`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
})

speed_vec %>%
  map_dfr(~{
    cars %>% 
      filter(between(speed, .x, .x + 3)) %>%
      slice_min(dist)
  }) %>%
  head()
#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
#> 2     7    4
#> 3     7    4
#> 4     7    4
#> 5     9   10
#> 6     9   10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Não uma resposta pra sua pergunta, mas se o objetivo é ter uma tabela com o valor mínimo de `dist` por faixas de velocidade, eis uma ideia:

- arranjar os dados com sequencia completa de `speed`
- usar `roolapply` para achar o mínimo por janela

### Com data.table

```
library(data.table)

r <- range(cars$speed)

dt1 <- as.data.table(cars)[, min(dist), speed][J(r[1]:r[2]), on = "speed"]

> head(dt1)
#>    speed V1
#> 1:     4  2
#> 2:     5 NA
#> 3:     6 NA
#> 4:     7  4
#> 5:     8 16
#> 6:     9 10

dt2 <- dt1[,
  .(speed_range = paste(speed-3, speed, sep = "-"),
    min_dist = frollapply(V1, 4, min, na.rm = TRUE))]

head(dt2[complete.cases(dt2)])
#>    speed_range min_dist
#> 1:         4-7        2
#> 2:         5-8        4
#> 3:         6-9        4
#> 4:        7-10        4
#> 5:        8-11       10
#> 6:        9-12       10
```

### Com tidyverse e zoo::rollaply

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

r <- range(cars$speed)

cars %>% 
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarize(x = min(dist)) %>%
  right_join(data.frame(speed = r[1]:r[2])) %>%
  arrange(speed) %>%
  summarize(speed_range = paste(speed, speed+3, sep = "-"),
            min_dist = rollapply(x, 4, min, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = "left")) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.))
```